# как уговорить xCode7.2 Swift2.0 на @2x и @3x

Tags: ios, swift

как уговорить xCode7.2 Swift2.0 на @2x  и  @3x
старший форум и Apple_ посмотрел...

```
var imBackGroundView: UIImageView!
func run0002() {

self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:  background[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(background.count)))])!)

}

// bk0001@2x.png = 750x1334 px xCode согласился...на iPhone 6
// bk0001@3x.png = 1242x2208 px xCode тоже не возражает...на iPhone 6+ все хорошо...
```

однако = хотелось бы...

```
  var tele : UIImageView!
  tele = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 510, 375, 160))  // tele0001b@2x.png = 750x320 px признает...на iPhohe 6

  tele = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 510, 414, 225))  // tele0001b@3x.png = 414x450 px признает...на iPhone 6+
                                                                                        // tele0001b@3x.png = 1242x450 px признает ...на iPhone 6 + 
                                                                                        // а можно и 1080x450 им все равно...frame есть frame...

  // но только  если присвоение по очереди закомментировать...для своего экрана 
  // т.е. графика в px признается как подходящая 

  tele.image = UIImage(named: "tele0001b.png")
  self.view.addSubview(tele)

 // конечно что frame_у скажешь то и будет...но все-таки - не вручную же переключать под свое разрешение...
 // а без frame = идет Thread 1 : bad instruction...
```

Comment: можно уточнить что именно вам надо? `@2x` и `@3x` система подставляет сама. вы хотите чтоб и фрейм менялся сам?

Comment: вопрос решился через UIScreen(c прибамбасами) правда чисто опытным путем - посчитать никак...нужно было чтобы на картинкe на iPhone6 и iPhone6+ батон остался в том же месте , хотя картинки разные по размеру - спасибо за внимание... @MaxMikheyenko

Comment: ну публикуйте свой ответ

Answer (score 2):

Как-то вы слишком странно добавляете картинку. В общем, добавьте все картинки в `Assets.xcassets`, потом ...

```
tele.image = UIImage(named: "tele0001b")
```

И всё, картинка нужного размера сама подтянется.